# script_score returns 0 in elastic 1.3 using lang groovy

Tags: groovy

I am new in elastic. I am using function_score to customize the score. here is my code:

```
body = {
        "from" : product_per_page*page,
        "size" : product_per_page,
        "query": {
            "function_score": {
                "query": {
                    "bool":{
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "range": {
                                    "price": {
                                        "gte": from_price,
                                        "lte": to_price
                                        }
                                    }
                            }, {
                                "match":{
                                    "text": {
                                        "query": query,
                                        }
                                    },
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                    },
                "script_score": {
                    "script": "floor(_score)*doc['boost'].value",
                    "lang":"groovy"
                    },
                "boost_mode": "replace",
                },
            }
        }
```

the problem is that the score always return 0.0.
 when I set script to:

```
"script": "_score"
```

It will return the correct score like 0.98977035 (a number between 0.0 and 1.0). also when set to:

```
"script": "_score + 0.0001"
```

again it returns correct. but when I use this:

```
"script": "_score + 1"
```

it returns 1.0 or:

```
"script": "_score *10"
```

returns 0.0(and any function I use such `"script": "floor(_score)"` returns 0.0). also:

```
"script": "doc['boost'].value"
```

returns 0.0 (doc['boost'].value is between 10 , 100)

I also tried:

```
"script": "32"
```

and it returns 32 (as I expected).so I guess that the problem is groovy. maybe when the numbers are big,they round to 0.0. what should I do?
thanks

Comment: You seem to be doing `floor(_score)` which will make `0.98977035` zero, then anything times zero is zero

Comment: it was just an example! but you are right! I tried `"script": "ceil(_score)"` and any other functions but the result is same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution but not the problem!
if I use `floor( _score*10.0 )` it will return the correct answer!(I don't know why)
and about `"script": "doc['boost'].value"` It convert float to Integer(I could not solve the problem for float yet).